# cmake add an optional dependency to a static library without forcing consumers to depend on its depencdencies

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg

I have a static library built using cmake and I'm trying to integrate it to vcpkg. The library has some wrappers for things like `ssl` using `openssl` and `sqlite` databases but they are optional and not required to used other parts of the library. The source files looks like this:

```
include:
core.h
ssl.h
sql.h

src:
core.cpp
ssl.cpp
sql.cpp
```

the source files `ssl.cpp` and `sql.cpp` include the headers from `openssl` and `sqlite` to implement their functionality but `core.cpp` does not need either of them. I used vcpkg manifest features to enable any feature and I check in the cmake script to enable features on demand:

```
if (OPENSSL_FEATURE)
    find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
    target_compile_definitions(thelib  PUBLIC HAVE_OPENSSL)
    target_link_libraries(thelib PRIVATE OpenSSL::SSL PRIVATE OpenSSL::Crypto)
endif()
```

Now I have another library which depends on the core part of this previous library and also built with cmake and vcpkg:

```
find_package(thelib  REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(otherlib PRIVATE thelib)
```

but cmake is giving an error saying that `thelib` depends on `OpenSSL::SSL` and other libraries but it was not found. When I added the proper `find_package` to find these packages without `target_link_libraries` then the build passes but now consumers of `otherlib` will try to link to `thelib` and will be required to find all the packages required even it is not used by the consumer.

I thought that using `PRIVATE` in `target_link_libraries` will hide the dependencies from the consumers but it turned out that dependencies of a static library are added to the link targets even if `PRIVATE` is used.

The solution I'm thinking of is to split the library into several libraries which depend on each other as required but for a small library and basic things like this it is very annoying and much of work.

Does anyone know how to instruct cmake to link only the used packages ?

EDIT: To clarify more the  problem is that in the `thelib-target.cmake` generated by installing the target and included in `thelib-config.cmake` there exists this cmake code:

```
set_target_properties(thelib::thelib PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "HAVE_OPENSSL;HAVE_SQLITE"
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include"
  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "\$<LINK_ONLY:OpenSSL::SSL>;\$<LINK_ONLY:OpenSSL::Crypto>;\$<LINK_ONLY:SQLite::SQLite3>"
)
```

which requires those dependencies to be visible when linking against `thelib` but `otherlib` does not need to use `target_link_libraries` to link any of them but only `find_package` to make them visible and also the final executable result will not include the libraries it does not use because adding a library to the linker line only adds it to the linker search set and if it is not referenced by the executable it will not be included.

The problem is that consumers are required to use `find_package` to search for unused libraries.
I see that some libraries contain many dependencies like `POCO` but it builds many libraries and consumer are free to link against any of them.
I don't want to create many libraries. Can cmake components solve this problem ?

Comment: If your static library uses functions from OpenSSL, then anyone who want to link with your library needs to link with OpenSSL; otherwise a linker would give "undefined reference" error for OpenSSL functions. This aspect is not specific to CMake, this is how compiler/linker works with the static libraries.

Comment: only if the user uses functions implemented in `ssl.cpp` will the linker error appear but for users who will to use only the core or `sqlite` part they should not face this error

Comment: Well, CMake cannot track how specific source files use functions from external libraries. And CMake definitely cannot track which functions from your library are used by the consumer. If you want to make a consumer to be responsible for linking the required libraries like OpenSSL, then you could create empty IMPORTED target `OpenSSL::SSL` in your config file. That way CMake won't complain at `find_package(thelib  REQUIRED)` stage in the consumer project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I got around this problem is by dividing the library into several libraries and link the required components per application demand.
I am not an expert in cmake so I used the template from this repo to get it: https://github.com/ClausKlein/cmake-example-component-lib

Answer (score 0):

> but cmake is giving an error saying that thelib depends on OpenSSL::SSL and other libraries but it was not found

> Does anyone know how to instruct cmake to link only the used packages ?

From the information you gave, I assume that you install the targets of `thelib`. You might be doing that as `-config.cmake` but that is conceptually wrong it should be `-targets.cmake` which gets included by a `-config.cmake` which contains the necessary [find_dependency](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.html) calls. For example the `-config.cmake.in` template in your case should contain:

```
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)
if(@OPENSSL_FEATURE@)  
  find_dependency(OpenSSL)  
endif()
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/thelib-targets.cmake")
```

Maybe helpful: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakePackageConfigHelpers.html

> I thought that using PRIVATE in target_link_libraries will hide the dependencies

no, static libraries need to propagate their transitiv link dependencies even if they are private. If it would be a shared library than it would be hidden for the consumer.

Comment: I use both `-config.cmake` and `-targets.cmake` the config file only includes targets fileand in the target there exist a `set_target_properties` which sets `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` to all the linked libraries

Comment: you don't need to care about the `-targets.cmake` file since cmake will do it correctly. Just need to add the find_dependency stuff into `-config.cmake` to make it work. I just mentioned that the user needs to supply a  `-config.cmake` since I had seen it quite often that targets get wrongly exported as `-config.cmake` files